# What was the ancient Jewish pantheon?

Tags: ancient-history, religion

I have read that before the invention of monotheism, the Jews worshipped multiple gods of which traces remain in various texts. So I wonder whether it is possible to reconstruct it and what the gods there were.

Comment: Should this be moved to Judaism.SE? There's probably more expertise that way.

Comment: Uncited sources.

Comment: Did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Semitic_religion#Proto-Semitic_pantheon

Answer (score 14):

One notable thing about the Hebrew Scriptures is that they don't typically claim that there aren't other gods; just that theirs is a jealous God, and thus the only one a Jew should worship.

This kind of attitude isn't really entirely unique in the ancient world. Most cities had their own patron god. A Pantheon was in many ways just the summation of all the regionally-worshiped deities in an area.

There are mentions of other gods or supernatural beings throughout the Torah. My personal favorite is [Leviathan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan), who based on descriptions in various parts of the Hebrew Scriptures, seems quite similar to the Norse's [World Serpent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B6rmungandr) (or perhaps a super fire-breathing sea dragon). Isaiah even prophecies a final [battle between God (Yahweh) and Leviathan](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2027:1&version=NIV) (which God of course will win).

There are also two other supernatural creatures: [Behemoth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behemoth) and [Ziz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziz), but they don't get as much face-time in the Bible.

[image]

[Baal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba%CA%BFal) is mentioned quite a bit in The Bible as well. However, that is basically a Semitic word for "Lord". So essentially when The Bible uses that word it is saying "one of our neighbors' Lord god, rather than our own Lord God."

Comment: [1 Chron. 17:20](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Chronicles+17:20&version=NIV) “There is no one like you, Lord, and **there is no God but you**, as we have heard with our own ears." Also, the leviathan and the behemoth were not gods. Most biblical scholars consider them to be large extinct creatures (such as dinosaurs).

Comment: @Luke - I said **typically**, not universally. There are certainly places where classic Jewish Monotheisim is stronger. Chronicles would be one place one would expect to be more modern. See the second to last paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_Chronicles#Authorship_and_composition

Comment: The Hebrew Scriptures never say there is another god ([Isaiah 45:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah+45:22&version=NIV)). Period. They believed there was one God and the Devil. Idols were simply objects made by humans. The only time the idols had supernatural power was when the power was of the Devil.

Comment: @Luke - With repect, I have to disagree on this one, and I think a careful reading of the parts where other dieties and their worshippers are interacted with backs me up. I realise this goes against some folks "fixed beliefs", but that shouldn't really be our business here. (and I'll note this was first pointed out to me by one of my ministers, who was trained at a mainline protestant seminary, so this view of the scriptures isn't really incompatible with Christian orthodoxy either)

Comment: Not sure which point you're disagreeing with, but Hebrew theology states that there are only two supernatural forces: God and the Devil. When the Israelites interacted with idols, they were interacting with the Devil or his demons, who worked through the idols.

Comment: The question wasn't about current Hebrew Theology. The question was about traces of *earlier* theology in extant Jewish writings. I'd heard the same thing, and this is roughly the explanation that was given me.

Comment: Hebrew theology remains relatively unchanged, from then to present day. What I'm arguing is back-able by OT Scripture. Even in Biblical times, they believed there was one God only.

Comment: In other words, the Bible is "Final Fantasy 0"

Comment: @Luke - AFAIK, Devil was not part of mainstream Juddaism in the first place, like in Christianity/Islam

Comment: My bad. "Devil" is the NT name used. However, the OT often uses the term "Satan" (not the "devil"). See Job 1-2

Comment: In Judaism, Satan is a good guy. He just worked for God as prosecutor. Satan simply means adversary. God himself is sometimes called Satan in OT when he became adversary for someone. Unfortunately, translators sometimes translate as adversary and sometimes transliterate that as Satan.

Comment: You missed Tiamat, the Sumerian origin of Leviathan and the antagonist of the original Chaoskampf myth. Baal and Beezlebub were the worship of the indigenous Levant "storm god" This was most represented by Hadad, whom Baal was a manifestation of. Hadad was also the patron deity of Bronze Age Aleppo. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal

Comment: Asherah is a glaring omission here as there is both scriptural and archaeological evidence of her worship in Israel.

Comment: "Do not set up any wooden Asherah pole beside the altar you build to the Lord your God" - Deuteronomy 16:21. "He will uproot Israel from this good land that he gave to their ancestors and scatter them beyond the Euphrates River, because they aroused the Lord’s anger by making Asherah poles." - 1 Kings 14:15. "They also set up for themselves high places, sacred stones and Asherah poles on every high hill and under every spreading tree." - 1 Kings 14:23. "They set up sacred stones and Asherah poles on every high hill and under every spreading tree." - 2 Kings 17:10.

Comment: "He took the carved Asherah pole he had made and put it in the temple, of which the Lord had said to David and to his son Solomon, “In this temple and in Jerusalem, which I have chosen out of all the tribes of Israel, I will put my Name forever." - 2 Kings 21:7.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asherah https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asherah_pole

Comment: @called2voyage - I kind of put Baal in this answer grudgingly, as there's no indication in The Bible that he's a real entity (unlike Leviathan), but he is super famous, so I knew it would come up if I didn't. But I guess if he's in there Asherah ought to be too.

Comment: @T.E.D. At the very least, the Bible indicates that Asherah was believed to be a real entity by some kings and priests, even if the Bible doesn't itself specifically address whether or not she is real.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a traditional pantheon of deities in historical Judaism.  The religion of Judaism dates to Abraham-(circa 2000 BCE) and it is Abraham who is considered to be the Father of Judaism, as well as the Father of Monotheism.

The story of Abraham, however, dates back to a polytheistic age.  Remember, Abraham was Mesopotamian and came from the Southern Iraqi town of Ur.  During Abraham's time, his Father, Terah, sold idols-(Terah's profession was not an uncommon one within Mesopotamia). In all likelihood, Abraham's family line-(that is to say, his grandparents, great grandparents and beyond), were traditional Mesopotamian polytheists and it is certainly true that Abraham's fellow  Mesopotamian countrymen, were centuries old polytheists.  In other words, Abraham, though a monotheist for the majority of his life, was still born and raised within a polytheistic family, town and country.

However, Abraham, at an older age, left Mesopotamia en route to the town of Hebron-(located in the Israel/ Palestine region). In permanently leaving Mesopotamia, Abraham would begin a newly independent monotheistic life with his family and particularly, his two sons, Ismail and Isaac.  But, when Ismail and Hagar-(his mistress) were expelled from the Hebron region-(at the insistence of Abraham's wife, Sarah), they relocated to Arabia, whereby Abraham would return for a short period of time to help build The Kaaba with his son, Ismail.

Both Judaism, as well as Ismail based monotheism, originated with Abraham. However, both of the above mentioned religions were originally and deeply rooted in Mesopotamian polytheism-(beginning only two generations earlier with Ismail and Isaac's Paternal Grandfather, Terah and his distant family line).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes they worshiped other gods**
When you read the Torah, people use idols throughout. Two examples are Rachel and Michel; Rachel hides her father's idols under herself during a period(1), Michel uses one to make it look like David is sleeping so he can escape the palace(2).

The Author's of the Torah aren't trying to make a secret of it. People worshiped other gods while worshiping YHWH. If anything it they are pretty honest about it.

**That does not mean they had a pantheon** 
Where does it say anywhere that YHWH assembled an avenger like team of other gods?
The most you get is complaints from prophets about them. Elijah got pretty hot and bothered about Baal.  He states one has to choose between the two, YHWH or Baal, not just make sure YHWH is tops (kings 18). 
Read "Isaiah 44:9-20" and hear a savage rebuke of idol worship, stating that what they holds in their hands (an idol) is not a god at all.

So overall **yes** this worshiped other gods and **no** there was not a sanctioned pantheon in the Jewish faith

1. Gen 30:34 (Now Rachel had taken the idols and put them inside her camel’s saddle and sat on them.) Laban searched the whole tent, but did not find them. 35 Rachel said to her father, “Don’t be angry, my lord. I cannot stand up in your presence because I am having my period.” So he searched thoroughly, but did not find the idols.

2.Sam 19:13  And Michal took an image, and laid it in the bed, and put a pillow of goats' hair for his bolster, and covered it with a cloth.

Comment: Actually, Yahweh is referred to as being in an assembly: "God stands among the divine council; He judges among the gods." - Psalm 82:1. That said, the exact meaning of this passage is debated. You are correct there is no sanctioned pantheon in the Jewish faith, but in the Ancient Hebrew faith there was (from a historical perspective). It may not have been sanctioned by God, but that's out of scope for a history site. 1 and 2 Kings are rife with passages of Israel's kings and priests setting up high places to multiple gods, and erecting Asherah right next to Yahweh in the temple.

Comment: The Scriptures we have today may call them false prophets and wicked kings, but at the time they didn't have the scriptural canon. So the closest thing you get to sanctioned is kings and priests promoting it.

Answer (score 2):

There were no Jews before monotheism. Judaism evolved from local [Canaanite cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Canaanite_religion) under the influence of [Persian monotheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism). Some historians speculate that the earlier Egyptian [cult of Aten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atenism) was the original spark, which was later refined under Persian rule. In either case, the new Jewish national identity was built much later around the Jewish religion.

The biblical stories of struggle between the faithful Israelites and the pagan Canaanites were written hundreds of years later and are not fully historical. If you read them carefully it's clear they were the same people speaking the same language, following slightly different religion.

I understand this is controversial theory whose main proponent is [professor Finkelstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Finkelstein) from Tel-Aviv University. But I find the narrative quite convincing.

Answer (score 0):

There were multiple deities.

(There is a wikipedia article on it if you want more detail and additional sources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Semitic_religion )

Short version, there were the Els which were the children of the Father god - referenced briefly in Genesis as the 'sons of god' who bred with humanity, often to be claimed as founding components of various cities of the region. (Their names appear throughout the bible), such as El Shaddai: God of Might, El Ohim: Creator God, El Eylon: God of Melchizedek & Salem, and a number of others. There were others such as YHWH (god of Abraham's tribe), Qanna (god of jealousy), and Lucifer (god of prosecution and the morning star).

The *majority* of these gods were later rolled into one god (with the exception of Lucifer) to create the modern Abrahamic god that we all know and some love.

(Note: List of gods may not be not exact. Some are called out in ancient documents, but others are extrapolated from knowledge of the existence of the roll-up process and its results. Multiple historical events resulted any history of Israel's polytheism largely have been actively and intentionally destroyed.)

As a note, the roll-up process was a result of the unification of Israel which was once an un-associated group of regional warlords who, in order to stand against external invading nations, banded together and intentionally merged their religions and mythologies into one, including creating an shared origin myth of slaves escaping Egypt (which archeology has debunked. - Wikipedia article for followup: [Wikipedia-Ancient-Israel-History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_ancient_Israel_and_Judah#Late_Bronze_Age_background_(1550%E2%80%931150_BCE)), possibly to explain their rebellion against Egyptian over-lordship to establish their own territory.))

Comment: Elohim is plural of Eloah

Comment: Lucifer is a Greek word, has nothing to do with Hebrew.

Comment: @Anixx Agreed. That wasn't Lucifer's name back then, that is what is name was changed to later. It's possible he had an 'El' name at one point, but we don't know it, and that's all I'm aware of that's left.

Comment: As for Elohim being the plural of Eloah, you're correct. Elohim is both a singular name for the creator god and a name for the pantheon of the children of El (arguably his children).

Comment: Also the angel names may be remnants of the children of el (hence why so many of their names end in an 'el' or 'al'), although there's plenty of reason to suspect this, direct evidence is scant, and it may alternatively mean they're puppets or avatars of the el. Old hebrew mysticism was really heavy on name-magic. [Side note: The Hebrew mysticism on name magic has some interesting implications [and I find funny] on Christianity since Jesus was supposed to be named Immanuel by Jesus, a name magic that would have made him god's meat-puppet, but she named him Jesus/Joshua instead.)

Comment: My personal *guess* that with Elohim being both a plural and a singular, is that El was the *original* name of the creator God, but when the roll-up happened Elohim was changed from a plural to a singular as a way to get a generation or two to buy in, and they were told "Just pray to the whole pantheon at once instead of just one" and then later they passed off Elohim as just one after a generation had heard only "Elohim" being prayed to. That's just an educated guess, though.

Answer (score -1):

There is a community on the web, http://groups.yahoo.com/group/canaanitepaganism/?yguid=192651149, their theme is just the old Jewish paganism (canaanite?). Surely, you'll find there all these old gods, including Lord El and Lady Asherah.

Comment: I suspect this can be just a newly-invented religion, similarly to how some Slavic groups invent Slavic paganism anew.

Comment: This site, of course, IS something of the sort. But their religion is based on the old pantheon. They at least are trying to be as close to the old religion as possible. So, as for the list of the gods, I think, we could believe them.

Comment: But I see, if they are as these pseudoslavic pseudopagans, then even the list of the gods can't be trusted.

Comment: I'm just curious (and not sure about whether I should post this as a question or not), but what caused the Jews to become monotheistic?

Comment: Because a guy from above told them so? :-)

Comment: Really, they didn't become such at once. Their local god became more and more important. And became a single one. And other gods were named demons, daemons, devils and so on.

Comment: The Cananites were (probably very) closely related peoples, and neighbors of the Jews, but many would insist they were separate peoples.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I think Cananites were many distinct groups, some ethnically more, some less related. The place WAS a crossroads, geographically speaking.

Comment: As I understood, there were many small ethnics, with common pantheon. The Jews was one of this ethnics, that lated changed and called their former cultural relatives Canaanites.

Comment: For a good chunk of the regions' history, the region was dominated by wandering and intermingling, and interfighting tribes. Eventually they came to see themselves as two seperate people, but not until after being the same people for quite a time. It's kind of like a free state and slave state scenario in the US pre-civil war from a nation built from multiple separate colony-states. They were the same country, but subcategorizations within it built up for quite some time until they later had a hard split.